# Upload file to server without using FileReference.browse()

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to upload file to server with the `FileReference` class.
the file is mp3 that was encoded in runtime without saving him on the local hard drive.

Is it possible to fit in the mp3Encoder into the `FileReference` somehow?

Thanks

Comment: why use the filereference class at all

Comment: Well I am not sure how you are generating this MP3 but you should be able to access the byteArray and then send that to the server using a loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the mp3 as a ByteArray (not sure how else it would exist at runtime if you haven't saved it to disk), you can use the URLLoader class, like this:

```
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("PATH_TO_YOUR_UPLOAD_SCRIPT");
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);

scriptVars.var1 = MP3_AS_BYTE_ARRAY;

scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);

function handleLoadSuccessful($evt:Event):void
{
    trace("Message sent.");
}

function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Message failed.");
}
```

Then on the server, you just need to save the stream to a file and give it the correct mp3 mime type.

There's a decent tutorial, from which this example is adapted, here: http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2008/01/27/as2-to-as3/as2-%E2%86%92-as3-loadvars-as3-equivalent/

And if you need to send your request as multipart/form-data (so it appears to be an attached file), there's a good example of this here: http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/